# Thymeleaf + Spring + text with html special characters not printing new line, instead printing <br>

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a client name which can be 50 characters long and it can contain html special characters ("&'<>]). This client name is printed in each row of a table. My requirement is I want to add new line after every 12 characters.

I am adding new line `<br>` from Java code than I am escaping special characters using

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4`

on HTML I am rendering it like this

```
<td>
<div th:utext="${row.get('client')}"></div>
</td>
```

On my PDF document I can see `<br>` printed instead of new line

I debugged the code from Java and this my client name at different stages in Java application

Client Name: `INVC _Client01 _Abcde_lkgyiop_ Kamal_nagar\"&'<>]a`

Client Name after adding `<br>` :

```
INVC _Client<br>01 _Abcde_lk<br>gyiop_ Kamal<br>_nagar\"&'<><br>]a
```

Client Name after escaping HTML special characters:

```
INVC _Client&lt;br&gt;01 _Abcde_lk&lt;br&gt;gyiop_ Kamal&lt;br&gt;_nagar\&quot;&amp;'&lt;&gt;&lt;br&gt;]a
```

Escaped Client name I am sending to PDF.

I also tried adding new line directly on HTML like this

```
<td>
    <div th:with="formattedClient=${row.get('client')}">
      <div  th:utext="${formattedClient.replaceAll('(.{12})', '$1<br/>')}"></div>
    </div>
 </td>
```

But it is also failing since my client name is containing HTML special characters.

Any help will be appreciated , Thank You

Comment: None of your tagged topics has anything to do with PDF. How is that involved?

Comment: Escape for special characters before inserting `<br />`?